# ' ReferenceError: _ is not defined ' : error is shown while use LODASH module in node.js , _.isString()

Tags: node.js, lodash, referenceerror

I have started learning node.js through various video tutorials.

Below code is not working, the output should be `'false'` for first `console.log()` and `'true'` second `console.log()`.

**This is my code in app.js:**

```
console.log('Starting app');     
console.log(_.isString(true));    
console.log(_.isString('Saurabh'));
```

**OUTPUT**

**in CMD :**

```
saurabh@kumar:/var/www/html/notes-node$ nodejs app.js        
    Starting app        
    /var/www/html/notes-node/app.js:25        
    **console.log(_.isString(true));**        
                ^
    **ReferenceError: _ is not defined**        
        at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/notes-node/app.js:25:13)
        at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
        at startup (node.js:136:18)
        at node.js:966:3
    saurabh@kumar:/var/www/html/notes-node$ npm -v
    3.5.2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to install lodash using npm like

```
npm install --save lodash
```

Then you have to require it in file say **app.js** like

```
const _ = require('lodash');
```

You must have to follow these steps to use lodash in your project

Comment: if this helped you, dont forget to mark it as answer